# Why are we supposed to prefer document.visibilityState to document.hidden?

Tags: javascript, specifications

I was looking at the [`document.hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hidden) specs [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#dom-document-hidden) to understand what exactly *hidden* entails:

> 1. If steps to determine the visibility state return `visible`, then return `false`.
>    2. Otherwise, return `true`.

> Note

> Support for `hidden` attribute is maintained for historical reasons. Developers should use `visibilityState` where possible.

[`visibilityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState) is another property that can return one of three strings: `'visible'`, `'hidden'`, or `'prerender'`.

`document.hidden` (as indicated by the above rules) returns `true` for `'visible'` and `false` for all other strings.

I am curious about the note. Why do they say that developers should prefer `visibilityState` to `hidden`?

Is it simply because `visibilityState` gives you more "power" (re: granularity) in that it's more specific about what state the document is in, whereas `hidden` dumbs it down by turning the four states into two states, "hidden" or "not hidden"?

I understand that this may only be answerable by the people who wrote the specs, but maybe they're crawling around here.

---

*A preemptive note*:
I'm going to guess that this may be closed as "opinion-based", because it'll attract opinionated answers, and while it certainly may attract answers like that, this can be answered objectively by those who wrote the specs, so I'll take my chances.

Comment: As an update to this question, where you mention the four `visibilityState` possible values, I would like to note that the `'unloaded'` value has become deprecated and thus only three possible values for this property remain.

Comment: @RobinBastiaan Thanks, edited it

Comment: Some discussion: https://github.com/w3c/page-visibility/issues/63

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks! looks like this note about not using hidden was since removed. Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notice of `hidden` being maintained for historical reasons has been removed in [this PR](https://github.com/w3c/page-visibility/pull/64).

There is some discussion [here](https://github.com/w3c/page-visibility/issues/63) about this change.

Answer (score 1):

I did not write the specification, but I would assume you are correct -- the introduction of `visibilityState` made `hidden` obsolete. `hidden` does nothing that `visibilityState` doesn't do better. It is likely on the road to deprecation, given their insistence that you use the latter.